# Is there a way to show call stack programatically on OpenBSD?

Tags: c, backtrace, openbsd

Linux has the `backtrace()` function, which is a GNU extension.

FreeBSD also introduced the `backtrace()` function since version 10.0, and NetBSD since version 7.0.

Is there any way to accomplish this on OpenBSD?

Comment: I don't have an answer if an API as such is available for OpenBSD. But if you want to implement one, please see if you could use "libunwind-ptrace" in OpenBSD. If its ported, use this link tutorial on fetching the backtrace .. https://gist.github.com/crimsonwoods/4122796

Comment: @AditYa Unfortunately OpenBSD is not supported by libunwind. I tried to compile it too, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure when it first appeared, but there *is* a libexecinfo for OpenBSD 6.1 which implements the `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` functions:

```
{openbsd-amd64 ~}$ pkg_info libexecinfo
Information for inst:libexecinfo-0.3v0

Comment:
clone of backtrace facility found in the GNU libc

Description:
This is a quick-n-dirty BSD licensed clone of backtrace facility found
in the GNU libc, mainly intended for porting linuxish code to BSD
platforms, however it can be used at any platform which has a gcc
compiler.

Maintainer: The OpenBSD ports mailing-list <ports@openbsd.org>

WWW: https://github.com/conformal/backtrace/wiki
```

Comment: I originally tested on an OpenBSD 5.8 where this package isn't available. But the question being version agnostic, I think this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

On OpenBSD, you can use [this implementation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/backtrace/).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about gnulib. The problem with it is that it's not compiled as a library but must be directly integrated into the project, which means the project must also use GNU autotools.

Comment: Can't you just copy the files and integrate them with your buildsystem?

Comment: It is not that easy because: 1. the header (execinfo.h) is not static but generated from execinfo.in.h; 2. besides the header/source files, there are also m4 files which contain macros used in the code

Comment: Looking more closely at the source code ([execinfo.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/execinfo.c;h=0bcd9f078baaa6e8b0119630024ad762d8299960;hb=HEAD) [execinfo.in.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/execinfo.in.h;h=67ab08127bb0ea12aca3a8ff766194cfa4da72a5;hb=HEAD)) it seems that the functions are not even implemented. The source file just includes the header and the header contains an empty implementation.

Comment: Oh, that's bad. There's another implementation at source forge that's specific to openbsd...

Comment: I searched for gnulib on sourceforge but there is no relevant result. Do you have a link?

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to work. The format of the trace is slighly different: `0x15f043f0 <backtrace+32> at ./a.out`, and addr2line or gdb can't tell me the line for that address, but I guess there should be a way.